# How do explicit routes fail to find the Controller

Tags: php, cakephp, url-routing, cakephp-3.x

I set up the following routes.  The routes are explicit and the controller is in src/Controller directory.  I did a git pull on the stage server and suddenly cakePHP (3.6) could not find the method, and was looking in the wrong controller.  Below are the routes that are explicitly coded.

```
Router::scope('/', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
    $routes->connect('/<foo>/methodOne/*', ['controller' => 'SomeController', 'action' => 'methodOne']);
    $routes->connect('/<foo>/methodTwo/*', ['controller' => 'SomeController', 'action' => 'methodTwo']);
    $routes->fallbacks('DashedRoute');
}
```

This happens with new controllers I create sometimes.  I have added the correct `namespaces` and `use` statements.  To fix this issue I make changes in the controller and then it works.  Any idea why this happens?  Anyway to prevent this from happening over and over again?

Comment: Please don't use dummy code/names, always show the real thing, and include the exact error message, including the related stacktrace (ideally obtained from the logs, where it is available in a readable fashion). The error page in debug mode can also provide helpful information. For routing problems specifically, the results of the routes shell can also be very helpful (`bin/cake routes`).

Comment: That being said, check if you're using [**route caching**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/middleware.html#routing-middleware) (second argument of the `RoutingMiddleware` constructor), if so, [**clear the cache**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells/cache.html) (`tmp/cache/`) after adding new routes.

Comment: @ndm thank you.  I did clear all cache.  There aren't any caching settings in the middleware as far as I am aware of (I took over after the last team was fired).  I am not too familiar with cakePHP, and so I was wondering if there was anything to run to show the routes like in laravel.